# JavaFX VBox getChildren().addAll() error

Tags: java, javafx

I have a small problem, When i want add textField, 
button and label to VBOX i have a error :
addAll() in ObservableList cannot be applied to:

[image]

in this place: vBox.getChildren().addAll(textField, button, label);

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        BorderPane layout = new BorderPane();

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 400, 200);

        TextField textField = new TextField();
        Label label = new Label("Average: 0.0");

        Button button = new Button("Przycisk");
        button.setOnAction(event -> {
            String textFromTextField = textField.getText();
            String[] splittedText = textFromTextField.split(",");
            double average = 0.0;
            for (String s: splittedText) {
                average += Double.parseDouble(s);
            }
            average /= splittedText.length;
            label.setText("Average: " + average);
        });

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(textField, button, label);
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vBox.setSpacing(10);

        layout.setCenter(vBox);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("App");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you have imported AWT components `java.awt.Label` and `java.awt.TextField` instead of JavaFX components `javafx.scene.control.Label` and `javafx.scene.control.TextField`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a good look at your imports!

In the image you can see that you used the TextField and Label from the 'awt' library instead of the 'javafx' library.
Make sure to change that and see if it worked out!

(Ps. Please post the full stacktrace in your question next time!)